# How do I resize the canvas content and get the resized (and compressed) image base64 data?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am playing with the `canvas` and have created a drawing demo.

Now I can draw stuff on that canvas and get the data with `.toDataURL()`.

Everything goes perfect except for the data of the image is too big. And I just only need a very small version of the drawing.

Is there any way (even possible) that I can resize the canvas to a smaller version and load the resized image data? It's kinda like to compress the image with pure JavaScript.

For instance, I let the user to draw on a 1000px * 500px canvas and resize it to 50px * 25px. The resized base64 data would be very small and convenient for further network-transfer. That's what I want to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You let your user draw on the big canvas, then you draw the big canvas as an image on the small canvas. Finally you get the small canvas image as a data URI.

The small canvas doesn't have to be attached to the DOM.

```js
let bigCanvas_img = document.querySelector("bigCanvas");
smallCanvas_ctx.drawImage(bigCanvas_img,0,0,smallCanvas_w,smallCanvas_h);


let url = smallCanvas.toDataURL();
```